# Request Ride on API - Range street number

Tags: uber-api

I am facing a divergence of racing information requested directly by the Uber application and my software. When prompted directly by the Uber application, the address sent to the driver is exactly as entered. When prompted by my software and sent via API Request, the address sent to the driver is with street number range.

I'm sending start_latitude, start_longitude and start_address.

Here's an example:
Start address: Av. Das Camélias, 263 - Nova Suíssa, Belo Horizonte - MG, Brazil
Start_Latitude: -19.932592
Start_Longitude: -43.975979

Address received by the driver:
Av. Das Camélias, 236-260 - Nova Suíssa, Belo Horizonte - MG, Brazil

Any suggestions on how to confirm that the driver receives the exact address?

Answer (score 0):

What really matters is 'start_latitude' and 'start_longitude' - because this is what will tell the driver what is the pickup location. So if you have those two parameters setup in the ['POST /v1.2/requests'](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post#ride-request-create) the driver will receive exact location. Address details are modified based on best pick up location - and adjusted by Uber Maps so that is why you are getting the street number as a range.

Comment: But why when I request directly through the Uber app does not appear this range of street number? It is exactly the number I put.